# Entity Framework: can I turn off AutoDetectChangesEnabled on reading from Local?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a database with layers and figures on layers (for drawing). I use a SQL Server CE, create database context on application start, work with `db.Layers.Local` and call `SaveChanges` before application's exit.

All operations with this "local" db are separated into two types: read and write. When I want to read some entities I'm not going to change it.

For example:

```
MainModel db = new MainModel(); //created at application start and stored as field of repository

public List<Figure> GetAllFigures(){
    db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false; //disable before querying local
    var res =  db.Layers.Local.SelectMany(x=>x.Figures).ToList();
    db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
    return res;
}

public void ChangeLayer(Figure figure, Layer layer){
    figure.Layer = layer;
    db.Figures.Local;
    db.Layers.Local; //manually call detectChanges
}
```

So the logic is call `DetectChanges` on updates after any change to allow disabling it on reading. I do reading much more often than changing and reading without `DetectChanges` is sometimes 100 times faster. Is that logic correct and everything will work as expected? Did I understand right why EF calls `DetectChanges` when query to `DbSet.Local`?

Answer (score 1):

Read everything with the AsNoTracking() extension so that the entities are not attached to the context.

As suggested, before changing the properties, attach it to the context, change the properties (layer)  and mark it as modified so that it will be persisted.
Also you can call DetectChanges() so that the modifications are tracked automatically

Comment: I've tried AsNoTracking, it's even more expensive than DbSet.Local with AutoDetectChanges enabled. (maybe this is because I'm using file DB with Compact CE)

Comment: I am not sure how you do the queries. Are you fetch all data in the context and then you use DbSet.Local ? This means that you must be fetching the data at application startup to populate the context. In this case you must use AsNoTracking at that time and keep the Figures and layers data in local lists to avoid the context overhead. The cost you see is not from the Autodetecton but from the Db Query

Comment: Thanks for you relpy! No, when I disable autodetection, query to Local gets faster up to 100 times (tested). Using Db prior to lists is because possibly in future I'll need concurrency here. Also in rare cases other parts of application (not only painter) need to query figures. DbSet is more convenient here.  Can my approach from initial question cause any side effects?

Answer (score 0):

After change `Attach` your entity to `Context`

```
Context.YourEntity.Attach(YourEntityObject);
// And Save here
```

Or use

```
Context.Entry(YourEntityObject).State = EntityState.Modified;
```